# Using SumIf() or SumIfs() over a range, with same Criteria?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a `SumIfs()` formula that is essentially the same condition, over a range.

```
2017    2016    2015    2014    Data
Same    Same    Same    Same    100
Removed Same    Same    Same    100
        Removed Same    Same    100
Same    Same    Same    Same    100
Removed Same    Same    Same    100
```

(starting in `A1` with the `2017` as a header)

Formula under the bottom right `100`:

`=SUMIFS($E$2:$E$6,A2:A6,"<>Removed",B2:B6,"<>Removed",C2:C6,"<>Removed",D2:D6,"<>Removed")`

The above formula works fine, and correctly returns `200`.

I just want to sum all the data in the "Data" column, where a value in the range to the left doesn't have `Removed` in any cell.  However, I'm going to be adding columns to this table, so it'd be nice not to have to keep adding a range and condition.  I'd think doing this as an Array formula would work, but I get an incorrect sum:

`=SUMIF(A2:D6,"<>Removed",E2:E6)` returns `300` (whether or not I enter with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd>)

**But!!** If I use `=SUMIF(A2:D6,"=Removed",E2:E6)` I correctly get `200`. Is that just a quirk, or is that actually going to be accurate, if I use that formula? It's odd, because it seems to work *opposite* of my `If` statement and therefore I think the `200` answer is just a quirk of this specific data and I shouldn't use that.

Is there a formula I'm overlooking? I'd like to avoid UDFs/Macros as well.

Thanks for any ideas!

Edit: To (hopefully) be more explicit, let's say I have to add 30 years of data in there (from like 1980 on), I'd rather not have to add 30 more statements to my `SumIfs()` formula. I'm hoping there's a quick way to do (psuedo-formula obviously): `=SumIf(A2:AA100,"<>Removed",AB2:AB100)`

Comment: FWIW - I suspect your `=SUMIF(A2:D6,"=Removed",E2:E6)` is just acting as `=SUMIF(A2:A6,"=Removed",E2:E6)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to find sum of **Data** column for rows without *Removed* in any column, you can use following array formula (confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>):

```
=SUM(IF(MMULT(--(A2:D6="Removed"),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(A2:D2))),,E2:E6))
```

It calculates [matrix product](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MMULT-function-40593ed7-a3cd-4b6b-b9a3-e4ad3c7245eb) of two arrays **A** and **B**:

[image]

Zero in the result array indicates that *Removed* does not occur in this row.

Your formula:

```
=SUMIF(A2:D6,"=Removed",E2:E6)
```

is equivalent to:

```
=SUMIF(A2:D6,"=Removed",E2:H6)
```

and:

```
=SUMIF(A2:A6,"=Removed",E2:E6)+SUMIF(B2:B6,"=Removed",F2:F6)
+SUMIF(C2:C6,"=Removed",G2:G6)+SUMIF(D2:D6,"=Removed",H2:H6)
```

as described [here](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/SUMIF-function-169B8C99-C05C-4483-A712-1697A653039B):

> The sum_range argument does not have to be the same size and shape as the range argument. The actual cells that are added are determined by using the upper leftmost cell in the sum_range argument as the beginning cell, and then including cells that correspond in size and shape to the range argument.

Comment: [Woah](http://www.reactiongifs.com/r/2013/10/woah.gif) - That's awesome. I will have to take some more time to study how that works, but it does! Especially since I just need to adjust the range one time, which I don't mind doing, since adding 1 new column takes the same adjustment as if I added 30 columns. Thanks a ton for this! I've never seen `MMULT` either, so will be researching that too.  Thanks a ton!!

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of a way to create a formula that will dynamically update and include a new column A. (Although I'm sure it exists) The alternative I came up with would be keeping the oldest year in column and adding further into the worksheet as you go, as pictured here:

[image: here]

From there, add in a helper column to add whether or not each row will be added, and then a sum of those results.
Formula in F2, copied down through F6: `=IF(COUNTIFS($A2:E2,"removed")>0,0,E2)`
Formula in F7: `=SUM(F2:F6)`

When you add 2018, you'd right click on column E, insert a new row, and the $A would stay at the front, but the E would update to accommodate for the new column.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my suspicions on the `"=Removed"` part.  For the other part, I appreciate the help ...but I'm looking for a formula that I *don't* have to keep adding to.  Say I need 30 more years' data in there, I'd rather not have to keep adding `F:F,"<>Removed",` 30 times, know what I mean? Sorry if that wasn't clear in OP.

Comment: Sorry about that, it's Monday.  I proposed an alternate solution, maybe that one will work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your help Chris! I appreciate it, but just FYI I went with BrakNicku's answer as it doesn't require a helper column, and only requires a little touch up when adding new columns. Yours does work, but my spreadsheet already has a lot going on, so I'm trying to limit the amount of columns added.